# Отправка определённого сообщения окну стороннего процесса (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть класс для захвата веб-камеры, основанный на avicap32 (vfw.h)
При подключении драйвера камеры к окну захвата (`capDriverConnect`) выскакивает диалог выбора устройства захвата. Если камера одна, я его прибиваю следующим кодом, запущенным в параллельном потоке:

```
void CatchDialog(){
    while(true){
        HWND DialogR = FindWindowExW(NULL, NULL, L"#32770", L"Источник видео");
        HWND DialogE = FindWindowExA(NULL, NULL, "#32770", "Video source");
        if (DialogR){PostMessageA(DialogR, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);}
        else if (DialogE){PostMessageA(DialogE, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);}
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

После нескольких закрытий окна камера работает, так как в выпадающем списке диалога уже прописана единственная камера. Но если камер больше одной, выбор по умолчанию отсутствует, и данный код просто уберёт диалог и ни одна камера не запустится.

**Какое сообщение нужно отправить этому окну ("Video source"), чтобы выбрать первую камеру? Либо можно ли вообще отключить этот диалог (чтобы не выскакивал), предварительно установив устройство по умолчанию?**

Comment: Судя по скриншотам в гугле, там `ComboBox`. Значит можно послать [CB_SETCURSEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775899(v=vs.85).aspx) только не через PostMessage, а через [SendDlgItemMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645515(v=vs.85).aspx). Параметр `nIDDlgItem` найдете с помощью [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460756.aspx).  `nIDDlgItem` - это `CtlID` этого ComboBox'а.

Comment: Но возможно есть вполне легальный способ указать первый рабочий девайс, не прибегая к манипуляциям с окном диалога.

Comment: @mega, узнать бы этот "легальный способ"... Знаю, что в реестре есть запись о девайсах, но клиент без админских прав, и должен вообще работать из-под гостя, поэтому к реестру дорога закрыта.

Comment: Посмотрите [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721085/webcam-video-source-dialog-comes-up). Там есть пара ответов, которые Вы можете проверить.

Answer (score 1):

В общем решил, но конечно идеально было бы установить устройство по умолчанию и не выводить этот диалог вовсе...

```
void CatchDialog(){
    while(true){
        HWND CaptureSrc, ButtonOK, ComboBox;
        HWND DialogR = FindWindowExW(NULL, NULL, L"#32770", L"Источник видео");
        HWND DialogE = FindWindowExA(NULL, NULL, "#32770", "Video source");
        if (DialogR){
            ShowWindow(DialogR, SW_HIDE);
            CaptureSrc = FindWindowExW(DialogR, NULL,  L"#32770", L"Источник записи");
            ButtonOK = FindWindowExW(DialogR, NULL, L"Button", L"ОК");
        }
        else if (DialogE){
            ShowWindow(DialogE, SW_HIDE);
            CaptureSrc = FindWindowExA(DialogE, NULL,  "#32770", "Capture Source");
            ButtonOK = FindWindowExA(DialogE, NULL, "Button", "OK");
        }
        if (CaptureSrc){
            ComboBox = FindWindowExA(CaptureSrc, NULL, "ComboBox", "");
            if (ComboBox){SendMessageA(ComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, 1, 0);}
        }
        if (ButtonOK){
            PostMessageA(ButtonOK, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
            PostMessageA(ButtonOK, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Осталось получить количество элементов в этом ComboBox-е, чтобы выбрать последний.
Спасибо за комментарии. Кстати, `SendDlgItemMessage` у меня не срабатывало, а обычное сообщение прошло нормально.

Comment: `SendDlgItemMessage` можно представить как `SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, nIDDlgItem), ...)`, т.е. он немного проще и быстрее, чем Ваш вариант с `FindWindow`. Вы наверное не передали в функцию верный `nIDDlgItem`.